# Kucoin Futures order has been canceled. Caused by: Cannot close a position of size 0

Tags: algorithmic-trading, cryptocurrency, ccxt, kucoin

**I'm using ccxt kucoin futures to create_order with a limit order entry with this following logic:**

``if **name** == "**main**":
# Example: Create a long order at a specific limit price with a 15% stop loss and 25X leverage
symbol = 'MATIC/USDT:USDT'
entry_price = 0.7341
entry_size = 5  # Positive entry_size for opening a long position
stop_loss_percentage = 0.15  # 15% stop loss
leverage = 10  # 25X leverage

```
create_order_at_limit(symbol, entry_price, entry_size, stop_loss_percentage, leverage, order_type='long')
```

`

When I run the code, its successfully created an order for me but the order was close immidiately after.

I have tried to modify the leverages by checking the correct leverage tiers as follow:

def fetch_market_leverage_tiers(symbol: str):
try:
# Load markets if not already loaded
exchange.load_markets()

```
    # Get the market information for the specified symbol
    market = exchange.market(symbol)
    if not market['contract']:
        raise ValueError(f"The symbol {symbol} does not represent a contract market.")

    # Fetch the leverage tiers for the specified symbol
    leverage_tiers = exchange.futuresPublicGetContractsRiskLimitSymbol({'symbol': market['id']})

    return leverage_tiers['data']

except ccxt.BaseError as e:
    print(f"Error fetching leverage tiers: {e}")
    return None
```

Based on the output, I set my leverage size, and the order is still being canceled.

Here is my full create_order method:

```
`import ccxt
import os
import time
from typing import Optional
from dotenv import load_dotenv

# Fetch API credentials from environment variables
API_KEY = os.getenv("API_KEY")
SECRET_KEY = os.getenv("SECRET_KEY")
PASSPHRASE = os.getenv("PASSPHRASE")

# Create an instance of the Kucoin Futures exchange
exchange = ccxt.kucoinfutures({
    'apiKey': API_KEY,
    'secret': SECRET_KEY,
    'password': PASSPHRASE,
    'enableRateLimit': True  # Adjust as needed
})


def fetch_server_time():
    try:
        # Fetch the server's timestamp
        server_timestamp = exchange.fetch_time()
        return server_timestamp

    except ccxt.BaseError as e:
        print(f"Error fetching server timestamp: {e}")
        return None


def create_order_at_limit(symbol: str, entry_price: float, entry_size: float,
                          stop_loss_percentage: float = 0.15, leverage: int = 25,
                          order_type: str = 'long'):
    try:
        # Validate input parameters
        if leverage <= 0:
            raise ValueError("Leverage must be greater than 0.")
        if entry_size <= 0:
            raise ValueError("Entry size must be greater than 0.")
        if stop_loss_percentage < 0 or stop_loss_percentage > 1:
            raise ValueError("Stop loss percentage must be between 0 and 1.")
        if order_type not in ['long', 'short']:
            raise ValueError("Invalid order type. Use 'long' or 'short'.")

        # Fetch the server's timestamp
        server_timestamp = fetch_server_time()
        if server_timestamp is None:
            return

        # Determine the side (buy or sell) based on the order type
        side = 'buy' if order_type == 'long' else 'sell'
        
        # Calculate stop loss price based on the entry price and stop loss percentage
        stop_loss_price = entry_price * (1 - stop_loss_percentage)

        # Prepare additional parameters for the order
        params = {
            'leverage': leverage,
            'stopLossPrice': stop_loss_price,
            'triggerType': 'mark',  # Use 'mark' for stop loss orders
        }

        # Retrieve the current position for the symbol
        positions = exchange.fetch_positions()
        current_position = next((p for p in positions if p['symbol'] == symbol), None)

        # Check if there is an open position for the given symbol
        if current_position:
            # Calculate the updated entry size based on the current position size
            entry_size = entry_size - abs(current_position['size'])

            if entry_size <= 0:
                raise ValueError("Entry size must be greater than the current position size.")

        # Place a limit order to enter a position
        order_result = exchange.create_order(symbol, 'limit', side, entry_size, entry_price, params)
        print("Order created successfully:")
        print(f"Order ID: {order_result['id']}")
        print(f"Entry Price: {entry_price}")
        print(f"Entry Size: {entry_size}")
        print(f"Stop Loss Price: {stop_loss_price}")

    except ccxt.BaseError as e:
        print(f"Error placing the order: {e}")

    except ValueError as ve:
        print(f"Invalid input: {ve}")

# Usage example:
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Example: Create a long order at a specific limit price with a 15% stop loss and 25X leverage
    symbol = 'MATIC/USDT:USDT'
    entry_price = 0.7341
    entry_size = 5  # Positive entry_size for opening a long position
    stop_loss_percentage = 0.15  # 15% stop loss
    leverage = 10  # 25X leverage

    create_order_at_limit(symbol, entry_price, entry_size, stop_loss_percentage, leverage, order_type='long')

`
```

What implementation did I miss?